# Why split.hpp is located in many directories

Tags: c++, boost

Trying to understand C++ library structure. Found that split.hpp is located in several directories:

```
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp
/usr/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/kmeans/split.hpp
/usr/include/boost/preprocessor/detail/split.hpp
/usr/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/detail/split.hpp
```

Why not just in one place ?

Comment: Because they do completely different things...?

Comment: Do those files look the same?

Comment: Obviously it's split into multiple directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all that `split`s are different versions of `split` from different libraries.
`/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp` is for string split.

`/usr/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/kmeans/split.hpp` is for some geometry split.

`/usr/include/boost/preprocessor/detail/split.hpp`
`/usr/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/detail/split.hpp`

are for some preprocessor split macro.